# PHP :How to fix hash_hmac() expects parameter 2 to be string

Tags: php, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to post a picture to TwitPic using Twitter and TwitPic API. But I get the following error.

> hash_hmac() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in twitpic.php on line 36

I think the error is here

```
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

when the $content is used again here

```
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $content, $key, true)));
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: try a var_dump($content) before trying hash_hmac, it might be a non string variable like null

Comment: $content gets the user information from Twitter, Twitter sends the information as a JSON result

Comment: No var_dump($content) is not working, still getting **hash_hmac() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given**

Comment: It is telling you the problem, object given, so what type of object is $content, and can you convert it to a string instead by calling a function on it

Comment: I think the hash_hmac use string parameters while $content is not accepted. How to fix this?

Comment: The full error message is like this **hash_hmac() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in xxxx/twitpic.php on line 36**

Comment: Rukshan read what people are posting and thinkg about it, don't just blindly try. You need a string. `var_dump($content)` says that `$content` is an object. There is your problem. The solution? Convert your `$content` object into a string or get that string part from `$content` you need to send with `hash_hmac`.

Comment: that's my problem, how can i convert **$content** which is not sting in to string

Comment: to answer that, we need to know what kind of object (or is it array?) is `$content`

Comment: Now var_dump got rid of the error but still the image is not being posted. I will post a new question about it because now it seems that the problem has been changed

Answer (score 1):

It's because hash_hmac() **does** expect two parameters. The first parameter is the hashing algorithm and the second is the string to be hashed.  [Check the signature and get some examples here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php)  As Rukshan points out, the types must be as specified.